# The addEventListener method doesn't work in JavaScript File

Tags: javascript

Here is HTML page. When mouse is moved over or out, the color in text should be changed.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="prjs10_2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <p> This is very <span id="int">interesting</span>!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is JavaScript file. Can you fix the addEventListener method must be executed?

```
var int = document.getElementById('int');

int.document.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
int.style.color = "#FF0000";}, false);

int.document.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
int.style.color = "#000000"}, false);
```

Comment: It's `document.getElementById`, not `document.getElementaryById`

Comment: You should _really_ take a look into how to debug JavaScript code. Your errors can be easily spotted with every decent debugging tool out there (e.g. try the developer console in chrome) and it would save you time and increase your coding ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. <s>You are misspelling `Element` as `Elementary`. Correct that spelling.</s> You have edited the question to correct this.
2. You are calling `document.getElementaryById('int')` before an element with `id="int"` exists. Move the script to just before `</body>` (or at least, to somewhere after `<span id="int">interesting</span>`).
3. An HTML Element Node won't have a `document` property. You want to bind the event handler directly to the element. Change all instances of `int.document` to `int`.

But if you just want to change the colour of an element when the mouse is pointing at it, forget JavaScript and use [the `:hover` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act).

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
var int = document.getElementaryById('int');
```

to this:

```
var int = document.getElementById('int');
```

Comment: Thank you I did change ElementById method and semi-colon from colon but It does not work. Anyway, It says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "document' of null.